# Unity C# make camera sway back and forth while keeping direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've seen other threads that want to make turrets rotate back and forth, however my question is more complicated because I want to allow the player to control his/her camera while the sway is affecting it.  This is to simulate the feeling of recoil when the player gets hit by an attack.

Ideally, I'd like to have the sway first up-right then down-left and gradually return to center using something like `Mathf.Sin(timer * Time.deltaTime * scalar)`

I've been able to get the camera to sway using Quaternion functions but when doing so, the camera becomes level with the ground until the sway is complete, or the player is locked facing north while the camera shakes.

What code can I use to perform the tasks above?

My camera instance is named `mainCamera`,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I've done this in the past is to have a `GameObject` that the camera is a child of.

Position and rotation of the parent will affect the child relative to the parent, but the player can still have control over the camera itself. You can then have the parent node swaying, but without the code on it clashing with the camera itself moving and rotating based upon player interaction.